# Previous Commit to another for Deleted/Moved/Renamed File

Tags: git

I'm using the following command to get the key of the previous commit to another commit, in context of a file:

```
git log --max-count=1 --pretty=format:'%H' COMMITKEY~1 -- path/to/file
```

But in case of a deleted file it will return an error:
`stderr: 'fatal: ambiguous argument 'path/to/file': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

So I tried something like this:

`git log --max-count=1 --pretty=format:'%H' --all --full-history COMMITKEY~1 -- path/to/file`

This actually returns a commit key, but always the newest, not the previous one. Even if I change the revision to `COMMITKEY~2` or something else, it will return the same commit key.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you used `--` with the first command?

That your second command does not work is easily explained by your usage of `--all`, as `--all` is equivialent to listing all refs manually, so you will of course always get the latest commit returned.

Actually you can abbreviate `--max-count=1` to `-1`, so using `git log -1 --pretty='%H' commit-ish~ -- path/to/file` is enough and will also work.

You only get the message `'fatal: ambiguous argument 'path/to/file': unknown revision or path not in the working tree` if you are not using the `--` that tells git that there is a path following, as then Git does not know whether this should be a ref that cannot be resolved or a path that might exist in the history.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with the 2nd command is that the `--all` argument tells `log` that, in addition to whatever commit ID you've specifically called out (i.e. `COMMITKEY~1` or whatever), it should include the histories of every known ref (branch, tag, etc).  So the returned value is the first commit it finds **from any ref** *or* the commit you specify.

But I'm not following how you'd get the error you mentioned form the 1st command anyway.  the `--` disambiguates the argument (at least, it does in my tests and according to the documentation).